# How parse a web with dynamic url in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Im trying to parse the management web of APC (UPS) like "https:apc-ups-example.com/NMC/XXXXXX/genini.htm" where XXXXX is a dynamic token generatec when you open the page. 
The page requieres username and password but im completly lost about how parse the url. After that i can execute the javascript to download the "config.ini" file from the ups. Do that using FTP/SCP/SFTP is not an option for security policys. All what i try fail for SSL and i dont know why.

What i have, the final url (ofc we need the token):

starts with: https://apc-ups-example.com/NMC/

token : XXXXXXXX

finish with: /genini.htm

Comment: You're trying to parse the web. OK. And?

Comment: My objective is download the config.ini, you can only do that using ftp (if its enabled, and ofc is not for security policy) or via web with windows.open function, after try, scp, sftp, ssh, i dont know what more do, maybe someone know how can i do it, because if i try via request, ssl handshake fails allways, i need download that config to complete one script to do compliance audit of the ups and download it manually from every ups in the company its a lot of time. Because of that im asking for help

Comment: Do you have access to the server? If so, have you tried scp?

Comment: I have access and yes i tryed scp (handshake error with fingerprint), sftp, now testing if you open the link "https:apc-ups-example.com/NMC/XXXXXX/config.ini" directly download the file, but to do that i need parse it anyway...

Comment: Ok i have the web parsed and i have the source code what i need, now im fighting with split the section of the code based on the / what he have